# Some other U subsitution techniques

Tags: calculus, integration

I just learned the tan(x/2) sub in class.

What are some other 'tricks' that I can use to integrate?

Assume I already know trig-substitutions, integration by parts, partial fraction decomposition...

Also, could you give an example?

Comment: the integration of odd and even functions with a symmetric interval. The definite integrals has more tricks than indefinite.

Comment: There are lots of 'tricks' in our book by R.D. Sharma ... I'll post them here when I have some more free time. But the worst thing about these tricks is that even if you know 100 tricks you still cannot be sure that there are no more tricks.

Comment: @Kartik which R.D. Sharma book?

Comment: @frog1944 mathematics class XII by r.d. Sharma